# How to pass user credentials between two services in REST

Tags: rest, authentication

I have implemented a REST service (RESTService1) in dropwizard that uses LDAP authentication using Shiro.

I am looking to implement another REST service (RESTService2) which will in turn make a call to RESTService1 . The browser calls into RESTService2, so the user will provide login credentials to this REST Service.

1. Should RESTService2 pass the username/password to RESTService1 for LDAP authentication? If yes, how should I pass the details (Base 64 header?)
2. In my RESTService1, I would need to have an authenticated user as I need to filter based on user entitlements and return data to RESTService2. How can RESTService2 pass user credentials to RESTService2 so that it can authenticate the user? (I wouldnt want the password to be exposed while passing from RESTService2 to RESTService1)

Comment: please define the TRUST level between RESTService1 and RESTService2.